# Adding custom message to exec 1 in shell scripting

Tags: shell

I want to add a filtered text to every STDOUT goes to a log file. Example : echo "custome message' exec 1 >> log file. However its no working.I have separate custom messages for STDOUT and STDERR. For STDOUT I need to add message as "INFORMATION" For STDERR I need to add message as "ERROR" And all the messages to be added to same file
for STDOUT: custom message 1 + STDOUT > logfile
for STDERR: custom message 2 + STDERR > logfile

Any suggestion on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this script file:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
exec > >(awk -v msg="Custom Message: " '{print msg,$0}' >file.log)
echo Out 1
echo More output
echo Last bit of output
```

We can run it and then look at the log file:

```
$ bash script.sh
$ cat file.log
Custom Message:  Out 1
Custom Message:  More output
Custom Message:  Last bit of output
```

`>(awk -v msg="Custom Message: " '{print msg,$0}' >file.log)` is an example of *process substitution*.  It acts like a file that we can write to and thus is suitable for the object of the redirection command `exec >`.  The awk command prepends the custom message to every line of output.

*process substitution* requires bash or other advanced shell.

#### Separate messages for stdout and stderr

This script processes stdout and stderr and then sends each to file handle 3 which is written to file `file.log`:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>file.log
exec > >(awk -v msg="Custom Message: " '{print msg,$0}' >&3) 2> >(awk -v msg="Error: " '{print msg,$0}' >&3)
echo Out 1
echo Some error message >&2
echo More output
echo Last bit of output
```

Here is a sample run and resulting log file:

```
$ bash script.sh
$ cat file.log
Error:  Some error message
Custom Message:  Out 1
Custom Message:  More output
Custom Message:  Last bit of output
```

Note that the stderr and stdout messages may appear out of order relative to each other.  This is an inevitable result of the multitasking required when processing each separately and then recombining.

Comment: Please advise how can I add 1 and 2 to log file. I have separate custom message for STDOUT and STDERR.

Comment: To combine stdin and stderr to the same logfile: `exec > >(awk -v msg="Custom Message: " '{print msg,$0}' >file.log) 2>&1`

Comment: But I have separate custom messages for STDOUT and STDERR.

Comment: OK.  Thanks for clarifying that.  See updated answer for a method to process both streams separately.

Comment: Hi. Adding exec trimming log entries. Don't know why it is trimming:
Current code:
>logfile
exec 1>>logfile
exec 2>>logfile
Above code gives me the right result

Below code:
exec 3>logfile
exec > >(awk -v msg="Custom Message: " '{print msg,$0}' >&3) 2> >(awk -v msg="Error: " '{print msg,$0}' >&3)

with this format log getting trimmed for first few lines. Its weired why but unable to get it.
The log file been passed as argument to another script and there the log entries getting trimmed however with the first method its not trimming. Any suggestion John

Comment: @Bicky Some of the details of how the second script is interacting with the first are not clear to me but, as a first suggestion, try replacing the line `exec 3>file.log` with `exec 3>>file.log`.